# LINQ count character apperance

Tags: c#, linq

Instead of looping over my string I'd like to use LINQ. How to do the following?

```
//  explode our word
List<char> rackBag = new List<char>();
rackBag.AddRange("MYWORD??".ToCharArray());

// How many wildcards?
int wildCardCount = rackBag.Count(x => x.Equals("?"));
```

wildCardCount should equal 2.

Comment: Err... your are using linq already, aren't you?

Comment: I am, but it wasn't working because of the double quotes. And I was hinting towards don't give me a for() solution

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Lots of unneeded steps there. Try this:

```
int wildCardCount = "MYWORD??".Count(x => x == '?');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
rackBag.Count(x => x == '?');
```

Comment: Since `x` is a `char`, it isn't equal to the `string` value `"?"`

Answer (score 1):

int wildCardCount = rackBag.Count(x => x=='?');

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a possible way to count up the number of wildcards, as an alternative to the suggestions using Linq. Since the ? letter means something in Regexes, we have to escape it in the example (and use verbatim string @):

```
int howManyWildcards = Regex.Matches("MYWORD??", @"\?").Count;
```